# Why is sudo bash needed?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I was reading the following code:

```
$ sudo bash
# cd /home/
# ./gitpull.sh
```

Why do I need the first line, what does it do exactly? What if I just did `$ sudo` instead of `$ sudo bash` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It starts a bash shell as a `root` level user.  You need it because typically normal users can't access `/home/`

The danger of what you are doing is you are in a root shell -- you can mess up your machine rather easily.

Comment: Running `cd` in a subshell (e.g. via `sudo`) is not a productive operation... it will not change the directory for the calling shell.

Answer (score 6):

You would be much better off doing:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'cd /home; ./gitpull.sh'
```

Because the commands invoked as root will be logged.  Invoking a shell directly through sudo avoids all of the security benefits of sudo and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo <shell>`, if it works, betrays a poor installation of sudo and a potential security weakness.

`sudo` should not be configured to allow arbitrary commands like shell; the purpose of `sudo` is to allow authenticated non-root users to run certain commands as root, without knowing the root password.

If `sudo bash` is allowed to any user, that user is root simply by virtue of knowing his own password.

If an attacker obtains the password of any one of the accounts which are able to do `sudo bash`, the attacker thereby has root.

The proper way to do the equivalent of `sudo bash` (obtain a root shell) is `su`, followed by giving the root password, not your own.

Comment: I don't get it. What harm could you possibly do with `sudo bash` (or `sudo su`, for that matter) that you couldn't do with `sudo evil-command`?

Comment: `sudo` only allows you to do things specified by the `sudoers` file.  It offers very fine grained control since you could give access to only the programs you want them to have access to.  If you allow `sudo bash` however, you grant a root level shell.  You can do anything root can do at a shell.  It gets around the advantages of `sudo` and `sudoers` and basically makes the user root.

Comment: Exactly those harms that you cannot do with `sudo benign-command`. `bash` is an instance of the class `evil-command`. You can craft your `sudoers` file carefully so that the only commands allowed are those that cannot do any harm (or whose potential to do harm is contained somehow), and which do not allow escalation of privilege over the scope of arbitrary actions.

Comment: Allowing 'sudo bash' for user X does not necessarily allow *all* users in the sudoers file to run bash.

Comment: Nothing wrong with sudo bash, buddy. It's a great way to get into a place where you can get your job done quick, and ensure all login scripts ran.

Comment: @DavidBetz There is everything wrong with it. The purpose of `sudo` is to allow certain users to run certain commands as root, without giving them the full privileges (i.e. the root password).  The idea is that those commands are sandboxed: they do certain specific jobs, and only those jobs, without allowing privilege escalation. When users are trusted to be root, you give them the root password.

Comment: @Kaz The situation you are talking about calls for SELinux policies, not sudo (that's the only way to be serious about security anyway). Once you give someone sudo rights, you do not get to choose what commands they run. That's simply what being sudo/root means.

Comment: @DavidBetz `man sudo`, `man sudoers`.

Comment: @Kaz, I admit I didn't read your full answer. Didn't realize you were talking about partial sudo. Yeah, that works fine, but once you give someone full sudo (aka sudo), you don't get to control (read: you don't get to choose/like/dislike/judge/comment on) what they do with it. I'll be using "sudo bash". The real solution is SELinux policies. Root should be controlled too.

Comment: @DavidBetz I don't know what you're talking about. `sudo` was introduced to serve the requirement "allow user X to run command Y as root", for configurable combinations of X and Y.  This is not "partial sudo", it is "sudo as designed".   The requirement to run any command as the superuser is met by  "su -c <command>" (which requires the root password, each time, for obviously good reasons).

Answer (score 3):

The infamous sudo is an acronym of sorts for Superuser Do.

It basically make a normal user a Super user for a short while.

In your command sudo bash , effectively you are saying Superuser do --> a Bourne shell ( bash ) Which opens a root user logged in shell.

If you just ran sudo the operating system wouldn't know what to do.
So in general sudo is followed by a unix command.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` allows users to run programs with the security privileges of another user (normally the superuser, or root).
`bash` starts a new bash shell.
So, `sudo bash` starts a new bash shell with the security privilege of root user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting `sudo bash` instead of `sudo` is specified to

- absolutely ensure you are invoking `./gitpull.sh` from bash and not another shell such as `tcsh`, `pdksh` or plain old `sh`.  I'm pretty sure the script's hashbang line should allow the script to specify what shell to run it under but maybe it was omitted for some reason or the instruction writer doesn't want you to rely on that.
- I believe if you start `bash` without other arguments it doesn't act like a "login shell" and maybe the script depends on that.
- a force of habit from the person who wrote the instructions (maybe he/she works in a multi-shell environment).
- perhaps the instruction writer is not very skillful or has bad habits from other environments.

Also @nisdis is right.  Plain old `sudo` just prints usage information.  But why not use `su`...